# customisation in module drupal 7

Tags: php, html, drupal

I am working on job portal site and in this application when jobseeker applied for a job,he will get the email and private message in the inbox but i don't know how to send same notification that jobseeker(let's say abc)has applied for job...to the admin/employer who is managing jobs.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you looked at the [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module? It's a pretty straightforward & powerful way to set up actions that can be triggered by users. You could set up a Rule for when a user applies for a job, it triggers an email that will be sent to the admin.

That should be a good place to start. It's a widely-used module so there are plenty of [documentation](http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/rules), tutorials & articles about it. Hope that helps!